# Accessing subclass property in overriden superclass's method. Possible?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, properties, overriding

To illustrate:

```
public class FooButton extends JButton {
    protected Integer length = 30;

    public FooButton(String txt) {
        setText(txt);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String txt) {
        super.setText(txt.substring(0, length));
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly for me, Eclipse tells me that `length` is `null` while passing through `setText()`.

Comment: Why are you using `Integer` and not `int`? Using `Integer` will introduce a lot of unnecessary autoboxing.

Comment: I don't know, quite new to java, I never ask myself about the difference. However, it was the cause of my `null`.

Comment: You probably also want to call `setText(txt)` instead of `super.setText(txt)` in the constructor.

Comment: yes, that too.. not well awake.. sorry

Comment: should work in that snippet, and actually can't reproduce ... there must be something else wrong in your real code. Please show an example that actually _has_ the problem you describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
protected int length = 30;
```

Comment: oh no.. 
I misstyped in my question but actually had "Integer length".  So I changed that to "int length" and it's good.. 
I think I've still some things to learn in Java :)

Comment: yep. don't really understand why it works now but won't with `Integer` but yes, It works.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give the data type to the variable.

Comment: I only forgot it in the question . In fact, I wrote "Integer length" in my code.. which does not seems to be the same thing as "int length". Have to google that.